# Pandas: Porcentagem de aceitacao e rejeicao

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Tenho um dataset que contem algumas colunas que me informam: usuario, situacao_requisicao, cidade. Eu gostaria gerar um csv que me informasse a quantidade de requisicoes de cada cidade, quantas foram aceitas, e quantas foram rejeitadas. Ex do dataset:

```
+----------+-------------------+----------------+
|   nome   |situacao_requisicao|     cidade     |
|----------|-------------------|----------------|
|  felipe  |     aceita        |      belem     |
|    ana   |     aceita        |      belem     |
|   fabio  |    recusada       |      recife    |
| fabiane  |     aceita        |      belem     |
| leticia  |     aceita        | rio de janeiro |
|   luan   |    recusada       |      recife    |
+----------+-------------------+----------------+
```

atualmente eu so consigo pegar a quantidade de aceitos ou negados, ou o total. tudo isso de forma separada fazendo algo assim:

```py
df = pd.read_csv("../../data/bases/data.csv")
df["nome"].count()
```

Se alguem puder me informar como reunir todas as informacoes acima, eu agradeceria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso criando 2 DataFrames temporários usando funções como `groupby`, `value_counts` e `pivot`, um deles terá o total de requisições por cidade, e outro terá a quantidade de requisições aceitas e recusadas. 
Ao final é necessário unir os DataFrames com `merge`.

```
total = df.groupby('cidade')['cidade'].count().rename('Total de requisições').reset_index()

requisicoes = df.groupby('cidade') \
['situacao_requisicao'].value_counts().rename('countRequisicoes').reset_index()

requisicoes = pd.pivot(requisicoes, values='countRequisicoes', 
                                    index='cidade', 
                                    columns='situacao_requisicao').reset_index()

total.merge(requisicoes, on = 'cidade')
saida:
    cidade          Total de requisições    aceita  recusada
0   belem           3                       3.0     NaN
1   Rio de janeiro  1                       1.0     NaN
2   recife          2                       NaN     2.0
```